# Ankh IssueTrackerIntegration Sample Extenion

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

I'm trying to get the sample extension project available from [CollabNET](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/IssueTrackerIntegration) to be recognized in Visual Studio 2008. If I understand the wiki documentation correctly, it says some registry keys are needed.

After building the sample project in VS2008, I found the `Ankh.Sample.Extension.pkgdef` in the Output bin folder, so I imported that as a `.reg` file into the registry.  After doing that, I see that there were new registry keys added to:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0Exp\Configuration\IssueRepositoryConnectors]
```

but it seems like, according to the documentation, they should have gone to:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\\IssueRepositoryConnectors]
```

---

#### UPDATE

OK, when I import the keys to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, the option 'Issue Tracker Step' appears in the Solution Explorer's context menu when I right-click the solution node, but here is where I am stuck now:

When I select 'AnkSVN Sample Issue Repository Connector' in the Issue Tracker Configuration window, I receive "'AnkSVN Sample Issue Repository Connector' does not provide a configuration page."

BUT, when I debug the sample project, another instance of VS2008 opens up, and I select the same project and in it, the page appears.

Why does it appear when debugging, but not normally?  Are there additional steps I need to take to deploy the package (I thought the registry keys did that)?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I did need to deploy the package.  When debugging, and a new instance of VS2008 opens, it does in effect do a sort of temporary deployment, which is why debugging worked.

I followed these [VSPackage deployment instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb458038.aspx), created a Setup project with a custom action, and ran the Setup.exe.  I then restarted VS2008 and the Ankh.Sample.Extension Issue Tracker Conf